# Cambio de lógica de cursor a consulta SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, impala

Tengo una tabla de trabajo que contiene información de los clientes, los prestamos que tiene y su monto adeudado, también las cuentas y el saldo de las mismas. Con esta información debo de presentar una columna adicional que indique el monto a debitar en base al saldo que tiene en la cuenta y el monto adeudado. Considerando que la información de las cuentas de cada cliente se repite según el numero de prestamos que tenga, y que no se puede indicar un monto a debitar que supere el disponible. 
Esto fue resuelto usando cursores, pero debo hacer uso solo de consultas SQL.

Esta seria una tabla con un ejemplo de los datos:
[image: Datos de tabla]

Y el resultado esperado seria el siguiente:
[image: Resultado esperado]

He encontrado alternativas haciendo uso de la clausula over partition, pero no estoy seguro de como aplicarlo.

Agradezco alguna idea de cómo pueda abordar el problema.

Les adjunto el código de la tabla con los datos por si desean correr alguna solución.

```sql
    create table table_test(
    customer int,
    loand int,
    debt_amount money,
    account int,
    account_balance money,
    );
    truncate table table_test;
    insert into table_test values (1, 1, 5000, 1, 500);
    insert into table_test values (1, 1, 5000, 2, 400);
    insert into table_test values (1, 2, 3000, 1, 500);
    insert into table_test values (1, 2, 3000, 2, 400);

    insert into table_test values (2, 3, 1000, 3, 3000);
    insert into table_test values (2, 4, 2000, 3, 3000);
    insert into table_test values (2, 5, 3000, 3, 3000);
    insert into table_test values (2, 6, 4000, 3, 3000);

    insert into table_test values (3, 7, 9000, 4, 10000);
    insert into table_test values (3, 7, 9000, 5, 2000);
    insert into table_test values (3, 8, 7000, 4, 10000);
    insert into table_test values (3, 8, 7000, 5, 2000);

    select * from table_test;
```

Comment: Podrías incluir el código con el cursor que están usando actualmente? Podría ayudar a descifrar la lógica.

Comment: Hola @LuisCazares. No lo tengo a la mano, pero lo que hace es recorrer una tabla de prestamos-clientes y por cada registro buscar en otra tabla las cuentas del cliente y el saldo para indicar cuanto puede debitar en cada cuenta en base a las deudas que tiene de los prestamos del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente consulta obtuve el comportamiento que esperas

```
;With CTE_List As (
    Select customer
       , loand
       , debt_amount
       , account
       , Lag( account_balance ) Over ( Partition By customer, account Order By customer, account, loand ) As prev_account_balance
       , account_balance As account_balance
       , row_number() Over ( Partition By customer, account Order By customer, account, loand ) As group_id 
    From table_test
), CTE_Result As (
    Select customer
        , loand
        , debt_amount
        , account
        , Coalesce(prev_account_balance, account_balance) As account_balance
        , Case When account_balance < debt_amount Then account_balance Else debt_amount End As amount_to_debit
        , Coalesce(prev_account_balance, account_balance) - Case When account_balance < debt_amount Then account_balance Else debt_amount End As new_account_balance
        , group_id 
    From CTE_List
    Where group_id = 1

    Union All

    Select CTE_List.customer
        , CTE_List.loand
        , CTE_List.debt_amount
        , CTE_List.account
        , CTE_Result.new_account_balance As account_balance
        , Case When CTE_Result.new_account_balance < CTE_List.debt_amount Then CTE_Result.new_account_balance Else CTE_List.debt_amount End As amount_to_debit
        , CTE_Result.new_account_balance - Case When CTE_Result.new_account_balance < CTE_List.debt_amount Then CTE_Result.new_account_balance Else CTE_List.debt_amount End As new_account_balance
        , CTE_List.group_id 
    From CTE_List
       Inner Join CTE_Result
          On CTE_Result.customer = CTE_List.customer
          And CTE_Result.account = CTE_List.account
          And CTE_Result.group_id = CTE_List.group_id - 1
)

Select customer, loand, debt_amount, account, account_balance, amount_to_debit, new_account_balance 
From CTE_Result
Order By customer, account, loand
```

Básicamente lo que hago es usar una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (dado que no especificas versión de SQL con la que esperas que funcione) en la que agrego una secuencia relativa a un grupo customer-account por medio de [Funciones de Agrupamiento](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Después hago otra CTE, esta vez si recursiva en donde en la primera parte busco el primero registro para tener el saldo inicial y después voy haciendo la recursividad para ir recalculando el saldo actual para cada movimiento, con lo que recreas el comportamiento de un cursor.

Finalmente le di una salida con una columna adicional new_account_balance y un ordenamiento para mejorar la lectura de los movimientos, sin embargo para generar la misma salida que esperas obtener tendrías que eliminar la nueva columna y definir el ordenamiento

```
Order By customer, loand, account
```

Puedes probar el código en este [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eff68/49)

Comment: Gracias Hamid. Funciona muy bien, pero hay caso en el que no muestra el valor correcto. Para el cliente 3 con el prestamos 7 se indica que se debitara la totalidad de la deuda con el saldo de la cuenta 4, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero dos registros mas abajo se indica que se pague 2000 nuevamente para ese prestamo tomando el saldo de la cuenta 5, cuando en este punto ya se habria pagado la totalidad con lo que se debita de la cuenta 4. No se si me expliqué.

Comment: No, de hecho te comento de lo que yo pude interpretar tienes clientes y cada cliente puede tener múltiples cuentas y sobre cada cuenta se hacen prestamos. Y si te fijas en la data que ingresaste repites prestamos para un mismo cliente y cuenta. En caso tal que no sea justamente esa la lógica toca cambiar un poco el script para ya no tener los datos a partir de un solo set de datos si no tener las cuentas de clientes con su saldo por un lado y los prestamos realizados por otro e ir cruzando lo que alcance.

Comment: Sí creo que ese es el camino. En realidad la relacion de la informacion es la sigiente:
- Un cliente puede tener varios prestamos 
- Un cliente puede tener varias cuentas
- El saldo de las cuentas puede usarse para pagar varios prestamos del cliente
- Solo se debe considerar que exista saldo en cada cuenta para cubrir los pagos de los que se adeude.

Comment: Bueno en ese orden de ideas no se debe partir a partir de ese listado que muestras que asumo es un select que armaste y agregaste la columna de cuanto debitar por transacción en excel... en su lugar replantea la fuente de datos a dos origenes el listado de saldos de cuentas y el listado de prestamos para que los cruces con una lógica similar a la mostrada con CTE.

Comment: Gracias! Intentaré replantear la solución para ver si lo consigo.